# break the loop when the function returns

Tags: c++

I want to have a function which takes an instream as a parameter. I want to have a int, and when it is not an int, I want it to skip the rest of the loop and start the next loop. something like this:

```
while(!done) {
    int n = read_int(cin);
    //when it doesn't return a int, how can i break the loop?
}

int read_int(istream& stream) {
    int i;

    if (stream >> i) return i;
    else {
        cout << "Could not read an integer value!" << endl;
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
        return i;
    }
}
```

is there anyway to achieve this? the while loop doesn't really like this, there are some code after the variable declaration.

Comment: Post some compilable code.

Comment: I think that the only case when it doesn't return an int, is when it returns a `null`, otherwise, i will always be an int.

Comment: just write the word break;?

Comment: @UnholySheep, you're right, I meant the case when the stream would be empty.

Comment: @Samha' `null`? How would `NULL` or a `nullptr_t` be represented by an `int`?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to indicate that the function did not manage to successfully read a value, you should return an additional value that indicates this. One simple solution is to return a `bool` indicating success or failure and making the `int` an "out parameter":

```
while(!done) {
    int n;
    const bool result = try_read_int(std::cin, n);
    if(!result) continue;
    // code if read was successful
}

bool try_read_int(std::istream& stream, int& value) {
    int i;
    if (stream >> i) {
       value = i;
       return true;
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "Could not read an integer value!" << std::endl;
        std::cin.clear();
        std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
        return false;
    }
}
```

Other options include returning a `struct` containing the boolean and integer (e.g.: `std::pair<bool, int>`) or throwing an exception (and catching it inside the `while` loop).

Note that sometimes programmers use "special return values" to indicate failure of functions, but personally I'd avoid doing this in favor of the solutions suggested above.